# Google Sheets - Auto import data from sheet 1 and not have it delete from the new sheet 2

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I used IMPORTRANGE to connect my two google sheets. Sheet1 has information on things we need to order, Sheet2 is used as a storage for everything once it has been ordered. However, I want the data in Sheet1 to be deleted as it is ordered but then it deletes from Sheet2.

How can I get information from Sheet1 to auto copy to Sheet2 based on the Order#, and not be deleted when it is removed from Sheet1?

Comment: Can you show a sample sheet showing your data? Also, show the behavior you want to have since it is hard to visualize just based on your post. A before and after image/sheet would be nice. Make sure to have the sheet publicly available to see.

Answer (score 0):

You need a script if you want to achieve that by deleting the rows in Sheet1.

If you want to use only Sheets standard formulas, there is another option that might satisfy the use case, but without actually deleting the rows from Sheet1.

What you need to do is add a new yes/no or checkbox column (named "deleted" or similar) to Sheet1. When you want to "delete" a row, you will just check the checkbox in that column.

On Sheet2 you will wrap the `IMPORTRANGE` into `QUERY`, something like

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(...), "select * where Col1=TRUE")
```

in case you first column in Sheet1 is a checkbox that is selected if a row is marked as "deleted".

Answer (score 0):

If a script is an option, and you want the row actually deleted in **Sheet1**, and still can add a dedicated column for checkbox (preferably the first column), then this will solve your issue.

See **Script** and **Output** for reference.

#### Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var value = e.value;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  // if checkbox checked is in Sheet1!A:A
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' && value == 'TRUE' && range.getColumn() == 1) {
    // fetch what row number is ticked
    row = range.getRow();
    // append the data on the checked row on the last row of Sheet2
    sheet.getParent().getSheetByName('Sheet2').appendRow(sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat());
    // delete row in Sheet1 afterwards
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Script above will transfer then delete the row upon checking the row's checkbox

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Creating the script without adding a checkbox on the first column will have to be a bit harder and a hassle since `onEdit` doesn't hold the `oldValue` when deleting a row.
- `OnChange` can detect deletion of row but still doesn't have the deleted values saved.